# replace fpos_t and fpos_t._pos in different platform

Tags: c++

In Linux(ubuntu) fpos_t is in a struct

```
typedef fpos_t {
    size_t _pos,
    size_t _state
}
```

In Windows, fpos_t is not defined. In the code base, it is defined in this way.

```
#ifndef _FPOS_T_DEFINED
typedef __int64 fpos_t;
#define _FPOS_T_DEFINED
#endif  /* _FPOS_T_DEFINED */
```

However, in my code

```
foo () {
    fpos_t fsize;
    fgetpos(fp, &fsize);    // Function A

    bar.len = (unsigned int)fsize;                      // for windows  Function B      
    bar.body = (char *)SAFE_MALLOC( (size_t)fsize);     // for windows
    //bar.len = (unsigned int)fsize._pos;                   // for linux Function B
    //bar.body = (char *)SAFE_MALLOC( (size_t)fsize._pos);// for linux
}
```

Question is what is the elegant way to substitute the fsize._pos to fsize when compiled in different platform. 
Method I knew

```
#if defined(LINUX)
    //code for linux
#else 
    //code for windows
#endif
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `fpos_t` structure is defined to be opaque; there is no portable way to extract a file offset from an `fpos_t` ([Cast fpos_t to int or char](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8621308/cast-fpos-t-to-int-or-char)).

If you want to get the byte offset of a file position, open the file **in binary mode** and use `ftello` ([ftello/fseeko vs fgetpos/fsetpos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12119132/ftello-fseeko-vs-fgetpos-fsetpos?rq=1)).

Comment: To generalize this question, not particularly for fpos_t. How should I handle this situation that in different system a variable is defined in two different types. However, some API calls won't effect by this changes, but some do. Like this case, function A doesn't have issue, but function B has.

Comment: @zero in general, you can abstract the non-portable operation into a (possibly inline) function, and place the platform-specific code in the definition of that function, using `#ifdef` etc.

Comment: Thanks, That's what I thought. Maybe this is the best way to do this.