# C: SEEK_END in a printf shows unexpected value

Tags: c

When I use `SEEK_END`, I expect it to correspond to the position of the last character in the stream. But inside a printf it seems like it does not.

I have a file that contains 1010 characters. I open it with `fopen`, then I try to print the position of the last character of this file:

```
printf("Last position is: %d\n", SEEK_END);
```

The output is `Last position is: 2` whereas I expect it to be `Last position is: 1010`. `2` does not correspond to the last line or last column, since I have 101 lines of 10 characters each. I don't know what it is.

Curiously, this code works well:

```
fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
printf("Last position is: %d\n", ftell(file));
```

The output is `Last position is: 1010`. But the problem here is that I am moving the virtual cursor in the file, which I do not want.

How can I print the value of `SEEK_END` without having to change the position of the virtual cursor, and more importantly, why do my `printf` outputs `2`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a misunderstanding.  `SEEK_END` is not a magical symbol that somehow stores the length of the file you're thinking of right now.  It is a constant, used as a code to tell `fseek()` what reference point to use for the specified file offset.

If you want to determine the size of a file whose name you know, and you are on a POSIX system, then you can use `fstat()`.  If all you have is a `FILE *`, then your best bet is probably to record the current position, seek to the end of the stream, determine the position, and then seek back to the starting point:

```
fpos_t current;
long end;

/* error checks omitted for brevity */
fgetpos(file, &current);
fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
end = ftell(file);
fsetpos(file, &current);

printf("Last position is: %ld\n", end);
```

Of course, all that depends on the stream being seekable.  Not all of them are.  If you have a non-seekable stream then very likely there is no meaningful sense of its last position to begin with.

There is also a potential issue with file offsets exceeding the size of a `long`.  `fgetpos()` and `fsetpos()` can be expected not to be sensitive to that, but their accompanying `fpos_t` type may be an aggregate type (i.e. a struct), and thus not direct interrogable.  You can work around that with `lseek()`, but that comes from POSIX, not standard C.

Comment: Ran the code above.  Got this error: aggregate value used where an integer was expected.  Got the answer from here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8621308/cast-fpos-t-to-int-or-char)

Comment: @Nguaial, yes, the first version of my code had that as a potential portability issue.  It arises from the fact that `fpos_t` is not necessarily an arithmetic type.  I have updated my code to avoid that issue, and added commentary about the related portability issues.

Answer (score 3):

`SEEK_END` is a parameter to `fseek`, it tells the `fseek` function how it should position in the file. You see 2 probably because in `stdio.h` it says `#define SEEK_END 2` although the actual value is unspecified.

In order to get the offset you need to use `ftell()`.

You can have a look at a specific implementation of fseek [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/a910abcd194830d2d113b3e183eb7df4d36cd92e/libc/stdio/fseek.c).

Comment: I would rephrase it... Something like that SEEK_END  is a type of operation but not a position

Comment: @EugeneSh.better like that?

Comment: @Jens gotcha :)

Answer (score 1):

From [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/File-Positioning.html) is possible to see that SEEK_END is an integer constant. It is not like a variable that holds the last position of your file. So, whenever you print SEEK_END value, it will be 2.